# Basic Question on Differential Forms (Chern-Simons Level Quantization)

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I came across the following [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555668/) regarding the boundary term in Chern-Simons theory (specifically the level quantization of the theory). I am new to differential forms so the following questions may be trivial, but either way:

1. In equation (12) of the accepted answer, where did the self wedge product terms i.e. $F_{D}\wedge F_{D}$ go?
2. Similarly, in (18), where did terms like $A_{S_{1}} \wedge dA_{S_{1}}$ go?
3. What is the intuition behind the last statement: " the contributions from the adjacent parts of the different patches' boundaries cancel each other". How do I see this?

Comment: General tip: Avoid referring to _the accepted answer_ as it may become unaccepted in the future. Instead use permalinks.